# Jquery UI range slider - Submit form after change value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rangeslider

I am trying to create form which will be submitted after change value in jquery ui range slider. There is my code which I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/haT5p/ as you can see at the end of jquery there code for submitting form: $('#range_form').submit().

But the problem is that console is giving me this warning:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and automatic submitting is not working.

Can you someone help me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is minimized. It's quite impolite to ask people to decode it.

Comment: Fiddle is not working and please do code formatting to make it legible !

Comment: If you want a simple example of how to submit form with values from range slider after the values on slider are updated, then I can create such an example for you !